# C# Selenium Assert Value Between Decimal Range

Tags: c#, selenium

I have some filters I am writing automation on and every time I think I have the solution, I am proven wrong. It will pass but then I change the values to be outside the range and it still passes.

Here is what I am trying to do. I have 3 scenarios on a filter:

```
$10 or Less

$15-$30

$30+
```

I have a list created of the price results in decimal. Now I just want to assert the results for all three. Here is what I have tried. I included all of them but my issue has been with the range where it is >= to one value but > than another. What am I missing?

```
Seems to be working:
case "10 or less":
List<decimal> listDefault = price.Select(s => decimal.Parse(s)).ToList();
Assert.IsTrue(listDefault.Where(x => x < 10).Any());
break;

This does not appear to be working:
case "11-30":
List<decimal> listDefaultRange = price.Select(s => decimal.Parse(s)).ToList();
Assert.IsTrue(listDefaultRange.Any(a => 11 < 30));
break;

Seems to be working:
case "30+":
List<decimal> listDefaultMax = price.Select(s => decimal.Parse(s)).ToList();
Assert.IsTrue(listDefaultMax.Where(x => x > 30).Any());
break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
Assert.IsTrue(listDefaultRange.Any(x => x > 10 && x <= 30));
```

When you do `.Any(a => 11 < 30)`, you're only checking if `11 < 30`, ignoring the input value all together, which will always return true (If the sequence contains any element).